# Would Ahri's Charm slow down Master Yi while he is using his ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

What happens if Ahri used Charm on a Master Yi while he is using Highlander?

> **Charm** 
>   (Active): Ahri will blow a kiss that travels in a line in front of her. It will deal magic damage and charm the first enemy it encounters, forcing them to walk harmlessly towards her, **while being slowed by 50% for the duration**.
>
> **Highlander**
>   (Active): Increases Master Yi's movement speed by 40% and attack speed for a few seconds, **as well as making him immune to any slow effects for the duration**. Additionally, killing a champion during the duration will refresh all of Master Yi's ability cooldowns, while assists will refresh them by half the base amount.

Will Master Yi:

- Be charmed and walk slowly towards Ahri?
- Be charmed but not be slowed?

I am wondering this because I am not sure if the Charm's "slowed by 50%" is part of the hard CC(which does affect Master Yi) or if it is a secondary effect that happens along with the hard CC(which Highlander can negate).

Source:

- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ahri
- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Yi_the_Wuju_Bladesman

Comment: Hunh. Intriguing.

Comment: I smell SCIENCE

Comment: sniff sniff *science*

Comment: @BenBrocka Science? Whatca mean?

Comment: I would have to say no in the regards that the slow does go onto him. So he would move at normal speed for the duration, which could possibly bring him past you, unless of course you keep moving away from him, but the charm should obviously still work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in the video, Yi is both charmed and slowed.

**My opinion**: Since walking slower means less forced movement (often an advantage for Yi), I doubt this will be changed in a future patch.

Comment: Very nice video. Thanks for finding that. Answered questions that I didnt even know I had yet :)

Answer (score 1):

The expected behaviour would be for Yi to walk full speed toward Arhi when Charmed.

Nevertheless, there is/was a bug where Yi would stay unaffected by the Charme (neither taunted, nor slowed)

Also, I read that "Charm" is a new type of CC effect. Thus master Yi is not immune to charm. This charm having the effect of slowing is not a trigger of a slow CC. Thus Yi is affected by both effects.
It seems that this is meant for such champion not to walk too fast when going back, which could make weird behaviour like running past the charming champion.

Answer (score 0):

I've played both heroes actually, and both against each other so I can confidently say that Ahri's chamr has a double effect of disable and slow. As wherein Yi's Highlander is a  speed enhancing skill with slow immunity. When Ahri hits Yi with her charm, she basically makes him run to her in his Higlander state with NO SLOW AT ALL. Simply put, Ahri is signing her death warrant if she ever lets Yi gets close to her without turret protection. Note that Yi's Highlander is instant, meaning that you can only apply the slow BEFORE OR AFTER Yi's Highlander is performed/finished. Hope this helps ^^